# git log --stat relative to subfolder

Tags: git, git-log

I want to display the filenames in `git log --stat` relative to a certain sub-folder, so that it's easier to read. How can I do this?

I tried `git log --stat sub/folder/foo`, `git log --stat sub/folder/foo/`, and changing to the subfolder before running `git log --stat`, `git log --stat .`, and `git log --stat ./`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`--relative`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---relativeltpathgt):

> #### [`--relative[=<path>]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---relativeltpathgt)
>
> When run from a subdirectory of the project, it can be told to exclude changes outside the directory and show pathnames relative
>   to it with this option. When you are not in a subdirectory (e.g. in a
>   bare repository), you can name which subdirectory to make the output relative to by giving a `<path>` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can issue the command `git whatchanged --relative` to give exactly which you want.

It will list like something like this for the `spec` folder, for example:

```
commit 0e1efda06b940d0b675a45884bc379bfb77537eb
Author: Andrew Grimm <andrew.j.grimm@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 24 23:42:44 2015 +1000

    Fix broken spec fixtures

:100644 100644 f6d6ef0... 2ae6d82... M  spec/factories/pmc_article_factory.rb
:100644 100644 bc30bfb... ecb98c9... M  spec/factories/pmc_article_list_factory.rb

commit fe77bd9fac39f6abcd4e19fac39d69cb64582f7e
Author: Andrew Grimm <andrew.j.grimm@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 10 19:31:25 2015 +1000

    Squash all commits for the repo, because of wrong email being used.

:000000 100644 0000000... 4bb2e7c... A  spec/affiliation_words_query_spec.rb
:000000 100644 0000000... f6d6ef0... A  spec/factories/pmc_article_factory.rb
:000000 100644 0000000... bc30bfb... A  spec/factories/pmc_article_list_factory.rb
:000000 100644 0000000... d23c1d9... A  spec/frequent_names_runner_spec.rb
:000000 100644 0000000... 5e48c86... A  spec/pmc_article_spec.rb
:000000 100644 0000000... b598abe... A  spec/spec_helper.rb
:000000 100644 0000000... eec437f... A  spec/support/factory_girl.rb
```

Comment: What are the two hexadecimal values associated with each file?

Comment: I meant the `f6d6ef0... 2ae6d82...` bits.

Comment: Those should be the related SHA's for those blobs.